# Using Rstudio to create Graph

Tags: rstudio

i want to make Bar graph from attached  data in Rstudio i want to show that what ip used what protocol and how many times

```
 Protocol

Source     DNS FTP HTTP IMF LLC SMTP TCP TELNET

172.16.112.100 306   0    0   0   0    0   0      0
172.16.112.50    0   0    0   0   0    0   0     24
172.16.113.168   0   0    0   0   0    0   0     15
172.16.113.204   1   0    0   0   0    0   0      0
172.16.114.50    1   0    0   0   0    0   0      0
172.16.115.20  158   0    0   0   0    0   0      2
192.168.1.20     3   0    0   0   0    0   0      0
194.7.248.153    0   0    0   0   0    0   0      2
197.218.177.69   0   0    0   0   0    0   0      0
HP_ed:9b:2d      0   0    0   0   0    0   0      0
```

Comment: data formatting is not good

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to build one plot for each IP:

After loading `data` as a `data.frame` with colnames and rownames.

```
par(mfrow=c(4,3))

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  barplot(as.numeric(data[i,]), main=rownames(data)[i], names.arg=colnames(data))
}
```

Your data is very poor, which makes the graphs have only one or no bar at all. If you want stacked or grouped bars you should have a look at the pakages ggplot2 or lattice.

[image]